# Drupal access without authentication depending on the source network

Tags: authentication-authorization

Is it possible to avoid the login page depending on the user's network of origin? We have a Drupal setup that can be accessed from a VPN and from the internet. We would like to make it so that users accessing from the VPN don't need to authenticate, but users coming from the internet do. Is it possible? Thank you very much to all of you

Comment: Drupal has a user account-based permissions system.  When you say "don't need to authenticate", do you mean 1) the entire Drupal website should be password-protected for users from the Internet, but not for users coming from the VPN, or 2) users coming from the Internet should have to log in with a Drupal username and password, but users coming from the VPN should automatically be logged in to Drupal (single sign on)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention
Regarding your query, it would be the second option.
Regards

Comment: Many of our members have had luck integrating their enterprise systems with their Drupal sites via miniOrange: https://www.miniorange.com/